# Synchronize some tables from two databases in different DBMS

Tags: mysql, sql, db2

I want to synchronize some tables from two databases in different DBMS (DB2 and MySQL). How can I do that without writing code in any of the applications that use these databases? Any idea?

The application that use DB2 has been written in Java, the other one is a SuiteCRM

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a one-time task?

Comment: no, should maintain a bi-directional synchronization

Comment: If you don't want to write your own code you'll need to buy someone else's code, in the form of one of the many replication tools available on the market. However, this site being about _writing code_, I suspect your question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adapt some tools to perform what you want:

- Have a master table (MDM) in a database and have a replication or federation in the other databases. (MDM software, or equivalent)
- Create a trigger in DB2 that calls a external UDF that writes the values in MySQL. Probably, you will need a similar thing in MySQL but not idea if that is possible. (In-house development)
- Create an alias table in DB2 by using federation (information integration) that uses the MySQL table, in that way DB2 inserts directly in MySQL. (extra license)